# VisualStudio IVSFontAndColor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, interface, colors, visual-studio-extensions

Working on an extension that deals with text editor colors.  I found the VsFontAndColorStorage interface, but don't fully understand how to use it.

Is there an example somewhere, or some example program that I can look at to understand how to store and retrieve colors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2005/06/03/425099.aspx) there it shows to write your new fonts to the registry and read it using the 
IVsFontAndColorStorage  interface